# Selenium-wire response object - Way to get response body as string rather than bytes

Tags: selenium, utf-8, response, httpresponse, seleniumwire

I want to fetch a response body as string in selenium-wire which I will eventually parse as JSON.

`response.body` in selenium-wire gives bytes string. I tried decoding it as `response.body.decode('utf-8')` but this gives decoding error.

Can someone help me with this?
I am fine with *both* solutions:

1. Either a way to decode the bytes string as normal string
2. A way to get response body as normal string in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this (not an ideal approach)
While making the selenium webdriver object, you can pass a parameter `options` in which you can tell it explicitly to give decoded request and response objects and not as bytes.

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem with decoding the responses. May I ask, what parameter in options did you use/set so that the WebDriver would pass the objects ?

Comment: `options = {'disable_encoding': True}`

Answer (score 10):

By default selenium-wire returns body response as bytes.

The documentation says:

"The response body as bytes. If the response has no body the value of body will be empty, i.e. b''. Sometimes the body may have been encoded by the server - e.g. compressed. You can prevent this with the disable_encoding option. To manually decode an encoded response body you can do:

```py
from seleniumwire.utils import decode

body = decode(response.body, response.headers.get('Content-Encoding', 'identity'))
```

And it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

put this:

`decode(request.response.body, request.response.headers.get('Content-Encoding', 'identity'))`

before you put the statement:

`response.body.decode('utf-8')`

the full code:

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from seleniumwire.utils import decode as sw_decode

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get(url)

for request in browser.requests:
    if request.url == url:
        data = sw_decode(request.response.body, request.response.headers.get('Content-Encoding', 'identity'))
        data = data.decode("utf8")
        print(type(data))
        break

browser.quit()
```

the output:

`<class 'str'>`

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my solution, It's work for me.

In python >= 3.5.x

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
import brotli

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')

for request in driver.requests:
    if request.url == "https://www.facebook.com/":
        resp = request.response.body
        resp = brotli.decompress(resp)
        print(resp[0:200].decode("utf-8"))

driver.quit()
```

Comment: I don't want to hardcode brotlyi into my code. What if it was gzip for some reason?

Answer (score -1):

None of these are needed.

Add a translation to the end of the variable you get and it's done.

My code ex:

```py
requestBody = ''
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        if request.url == 'https://api.ex.com/v1':
            requestBody = request.body.decode("utf-8")
```

My solution:

request.body**.decode("utf-8")**